# Azcopy throws error while executing via Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I am using the Azcopy tool to copy a storage account to another. While executing the command using terminal it executes perfectly. But while executing the same using Terraform's local-executioner it throws an error. Please find the code and error below.

Code:

```
resource "null_resource" "backup" {
      provisioner "local-exec" {
     command= <<EOF
        azcopy cp "https://${var.src_storage_acc_name}.blob.core.windows.net${var.src_sas}" "https://${var.dest_storage_acc_name}.blob.core.windows.net${var.dest_sas}"
        EOF
  }
}
```

Error:

```
 Error running command '        azcopy cp "https://strsrc.blob.core.windows.net?[SAS]" "https://strdest.blob.core.windows.net?[SAS]"
': exit status 1. Output: INFO: The parameters you supplied were Source: '"https://strsrc.blob.core.windows.net?[SAS]-REDACTED- of type Local, and Destination: '"https://strdest.blob.core.windows.net?[SAS]-REDACTED- of type Local
INFO: Based on the parameters supplied, a valid source-destination combination could not automatically be found. Please check the parameters you supplied.  If they are correct, please specify an exact source and destination type using the --from-to switch. Valid values are two-word phases of the form BlobLocal, LocalBlob etc.  Use the word 'Blob' for Blob Storage, 'Local' for the local file system, 'File' for Azure Files, and 'BlobFS' for ADLS Gen2. If you need a combination that is not supported yet, please log an issue on the AzCopy GitHub issues list.

failed to parse user input due to error: the inferred source/destination combination could not be identified, or is currently not supported
```

Please provide your thoughts on this.

Comment: Provided the working example from command line so we can compare.

Comment: azcopy cp "https://strsrc.blob.core.windows.net?[SAS]" "https://strdest.blob.core.windows.net?[SAS]" this the working example

Comment: Are you executing the command via Terraform in Windows?

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. It throws an error when executing the command via Terraform in Windows whereas executing directly in Windows works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Today I needed to implement a similar task, and I used the `azcopy cp` command with `--recursive=true` option which is given in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy).

It successfully copied all contents of the source container to the destination.

```
Copy all blob containers, directories, and blobs from storage account to another by using a SAS token:

  - azcopy cp "https://[srcaccount].blob.core.windows.net?[SAS]" "https://[destaccount].blob.core.windows.net?[SAS]" --recursive=true
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but actually I want to copy the whole storage account containers to another so that the path doesn't matter

Comment: Do you provide a question mark between the container URL and SAS? In your terraform code, I don't see such a question mark.

Comment: The question mark is created automatically with SAS

Answer (score 0):

`azcopy` only support certain combinations of source and destination types (blob, Gen1, Gen2, S3, Local file system, ...) for `copy` sub-command.

`azcopy` tries to guess source/destination types based on URL & params.

This error means that

1. you're trying to use a combination that isn't supported OR

   - Nothing you can do. Raise a issue as suggested. They'll probably just ignore it like [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/1450) or [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/507).
2. there is something wrong with your URL. E.g. you have `blob.core.windows.net` when you should've had `dfs.core.windows.net` or vice versa. This in turn causes mis-identification of source and destination types.

   - If you're sure that the combination is supported then you can tell `azcopy` the types using `--from-to`. Ironically, when you use a combination that isn't supported (e.g. `BlobFSBlobFS`), it gives the same error message instead of saying "source destination combination not supported).
   - When dealing with Gen2, you could use `blob` instead of `dfs` in the URL to make it use older (blob/Gen1) APIs to interact with your Gen2 account. Though less performant, it still might work.

- 'Blob' for Blob Storage
- 'Local' for the local file system
- 'File' for Azure Files
- 'BlobFS' for ADLS Gen2

---

As of now following combinations are supported [per documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy#synopsis):

- local <-> Azure Blob (SAS or OAuth authentication)
- local <-> Azure Files (Share/directory SAS authentication)
- local <-> Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2 (SAS, OAuth, or shared key authentication)
- Azure Blob (SAS or public) -> Azure Blob (SAS or OAuth authentication)
- Azure Blob (SAS or public) -> Azure Files (SAS)
- Azure Files (SAS) -> Azure Files (SAS)
- Azure Files (SAS) -> Azure Blob (SAS or OAuth authentication)
- Amazon Web Services (AWS) S3 (Access Key) -> Azure Block Blob (SAS or OAuth authentication)
- Google Cloud Storage (Service Account Key) -> Azure Block Blob (SAS or OAuth authentication) [Preview]